# How to rename files with removing all characters from file name between first underscore and last 4 characters?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to remove all characters from a file name between the first underscore and the last 4 characters of the file name and keeping file extension.

So for example `crashmaster_01011990_12311990.txt` would become `crashmaster_1990.txt`

I can't just hard code for the first 12 characters because there are other files like `crashcarrier_01011990_12311990.txt` which will throw it off.

The below code isn't working, but even if it would, I don't want to chop off the last 18 characters. Rather save the last 4 and append after the first underscore.

```
for %%i in (*.txt) do (
    set fName=%%i
    ren "%fName%" "%fName:~-18%.txt" 
)
pause
```

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a programming question? This site is for questions (you show some code, explain how it's not working, and we maybe try help fix it). It's not a place to dump a to-do list.

Comment: Post the code that you've tried that isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution with extra code which most likely is not really needed to validate the name of a file to rename.

The requirement of usage of delayed environment variable expansion within a command block defined with `(` ... `)` is avoided by this code by using a subroutine.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
for %%I in (*_*.txt) do call :FileRename "%%~nxI"
endlocal
goto :EOF

rem This subroutine interprets name of a file being valid for rename
rem under following conditions:

rem    1. File name does not start with an underscore.
rem    2. File name does not end with an underscore.
rem    3. There are at least 4 characters after first underscore in name.
rem    4. A file with the new file name does not already exist.

rem The last condition is necessary to avoid

rem    1. renaming a file with longer name to an already existing file
rem       because that would result in an error message on rename and
rem    2. renaming a file which was already renamed before and because
rem       of that the new file name is equal the current file name.

:FileRename
set "FileName=%~n1"
if "%FileName:~0,1%" == "_" goto :EOF
if "%FileName:~-1%"  == "_" goto :EOF
for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%A in ("%FileName%") do (
    set "NamePartFirst=%%A"
    set "NamePartRest=%%B"
)
if "%NamePartRest:~3,1%" == "" goto :EOF
set "NewFileName=%NamePartFirst%_%NamePartRest:~-4%%~x1"
if not exist "%NewFileName%" ren "%~nx1" "%NewFileName%"
goto :EOF
```

For testing before really making the file renames either replace command `ren` by command `echo` or insert command `echo` left to `ren` in last but one line.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`